# Minimize distance between curves

Tags: optimization, b-spline, clustering, distance-measure, l2-norm

I have a dataset with values of multiple curves. An example plot is shown below.
I want to shift the curves (up/down) so that all curves overlap. This would mean the data points in each curve is scaled up/down by a factor.
I am not sure how to frame this as a mathematical problem (to minimize the vertical distance between each pair of curves) and determine the scaling factor
for each curve. I tried to start by computing the pair-wise distance matrix
but I am not sure what to do next.

Suggestions will be really appreciated.

[image]

EDIT:

The following is a sample dataset which includes that datapoints corresponding to 5 curves and coordinate inputs are below

```
scale =  1.5;
x1 = [0,4,6,10,15,20]*scale;
y1 =  [18,17.5,13,12,8,10];
x2 = [0,10.5,28]*scale;
y2= [18.2,10.6,10.3];
x3 = [0,4,6,10,15,20]*scale;
y3 = [18,13,15,12,11,9.6];
x4 = [9,17,28]*scale;
y4 = [5,5.5,7];
x5 = [1,10,20]*scale;
y5 = [3,0.8,2];

plot(x1,y1, '*-', x2, y2,  '*-', x3, y3,  '*-', x4, y4,  '*-', x5, y5,  '*-')
```

And the plot looks like below. I tried to do a piecewise interpolation using
a linear approximation to find the function values. Since the curves don't have a common x, I am not sure how the target function has to be selected.

[image]

Suggestions will be really appreciated.
Also, I only want to scale the datapoints $$\tilde f_i(a) = a \cdot f_i$$
and do not want to shift it along the x-dimension (I'm not sure if `b` $\tilde f_i(a,b) = a \cdot f_i$ + b shifts the function value along the x-dimension; may be I am wrong and `b` shifts the function value in the y-direction). And I also prefer to define a tolerance window/interval $\epsilon$ (user-defined) above and below the target function which will allow scaling the other curves such that they don't completely overlap on the target curve.

EDIT2:
I would like to ask for a suggestion. If I want to scale $f_i$ (move it a bit up) and also scale $g_i$ (move it a bit down) would it make sense if the objective function is expressed as $(a⋅fi − gi)^2 + (b.gi  - fi)^2$. Basically, I want to try and move both the curves towards each other instead of moving one curve towards the other.

EDIT3:
@Vladislav Gladkikh

I like this idea, this preserves the shape of all $x_k$'s i.e the trend of the $x_k$'s before and after shifting doesn't change and I find this great.  Could you please add a pictorial explanation of the third point?

I think overall we do,
$f(x_k) - \bar{f(x_k)} + \bar{g(x_k)}$
Here, f is the non-main curve and g is the main curve (i.e y values of the curves at the corresponding x values), and $\bar{f(x_k)}$ is the average.

> Then shift all curves toward the main curve so that their averages
> coincide within the corresponding domain segments.

I think I am a bit confused here since we are subtracting/adding the mean the $\bar{f(x_k)}$'s/ $\bar{g(x_k)}$'s computed at the $x_k$'s in the entire domain.  I am not sure if my interpretation of segment is wrong, please correct me if I am wrong.

Could you please clarify if we refer to a segment as the domain between any 2 points that lie on the curve xk, yk here. Could you please illustrate this in a figure, if possible?

Comment: Can you write the equation you are trying to minimize? For instance, if 2 functions are $f$ and $g$, are you looking for $\min_{x}||f(x)-g(x)||$ or for $\min_{x,y}||f(x)-g(y)||$? Also, which distance are you using? Or are you trying to minimize the average distance between curves?

Comment: Scaling sounds like multiplication and shifting sounds like addition. You use both to describe what you want to do. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Richard Thank you for the reply. I actually want to scale only the y-component of each datapoint i.e minimize the distance only in the vertical direction. I am not sure if multiplication would work here since the scale factor would move the datapoint in both x and y direction. So I guess I have to do addition or subtraction here

Comment: Is this plot a fit to some pointwise data that you’re not showing us, or numerical solutions to some underlying problem you haven’t mentioned yet, which is to ask “where do the curves and error bars come from”?

Comment: @BillBarth Thank you for the reply. The data points in these curves come from experimental measurements. Each dataset (curve) comes from a different study. These are not numerical solutions. I am trying to use this dataset for parameter estimation so I want to reduce the spread of the data in the y-dimension. I hope I was able to answer to your question

Comment: @PC1 Sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to minimize the average distance between the curves. But I am not sure how the distance between each pair has to be minimized. Could you please suggest an approach to do this? I have a pair-wise distance matrix but not sure how to use the distance matrix to minimize the  distances.

Comment: @Natasha you will need to choose an objective function to minimize. This is important, else the problem is not formulated clearly.

Comment: Upvoting as an impressive troll. Congrats @Natasha !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume you have a set of abscissas $x_i$ and two sets of function values on these grid points $f_i, g_i$ representing the functions $f$ and $g$.

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need a model how you adjust the curves, so let's combine the shift-and-scale approach and assume $$\tilde f_i(a,b) = a \cdot f_i + b$$

which corresponds to an affine transformation of function $f$. You then have to minimizr some kind of distance, for which usually the sum-of-squares deviation is used, which yields the problem

$$
\min_{a,b} \left(\sum_i (\tilde f_i(a,b) -g_i)^2\right)\\
= \min_{a,b} \left(\sum_i (  a \cdot f_i + b -g_i)^2\right)
$$

As usual you can now set the partial derivatives w.r.t. $a$ and $b$ to zero and thus obtain two equations for the parameter which depend on your data $f_i$ and $g_i$.

This will yield you the optimal shift-and-scale parameters for two selected curves. As you seem to want to overlap any of the five curves in the picture, just repeat the above algorithm for the other three curves.

---

So how does one solve the optimization problem given above? Evaluate the partial derivatives with respect to the parameters and set them to zero:
$$
0 = \partial_a \left(\sum_i (  a \cdot f_i + b -g_i)^2\right) = 2 \sum_i f_i (a \cdot f_i + b -g_i) \\
0 = \partial_b \left(\sum_i (  a \cdot f_i + b -g_i)^2\right) = 2 \sum_i (a \cdot f_i + b -g_i)\\
$$
and thus obtain the following linear system
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}\sum_i f_i^2 & \sum_i f_i  \\ \sum_i f_i & \sum_i 1\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\sum_i f_ig_i\\ \sum_i g_i\end{pmatrix}\\
$$

You can either solve this system numerically or analytically.
The analytical solution can be found, e.g., via the explicit inverse of a 2x2 matrix,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b\end{pmatrix} = \frac1{(\sum_i f_i^2)(\sum_i 1) -  (\sum_i f_i)^2}   \begin{pmatrix} \sum_i 1& -\sum_i f_i \\ -\sum_i f_i  &\sum_i f_i^2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\sum_i f_ig_i\\ \sum_i g_i\end{pmatrix}
$$

which exists only if the discriminant (the denominator of the prefactor) is not zero.

---

EDIT2: If you only want to scale the curves, things get even easier.

You should then minimize
$$
\min_{a} \left(\sum_i (  a \cdot f_i -g_i)^2\right)
$$
which leads to a single equation
$$
0 = \partial_a \left(\sum_i (  a \cdot f_i -g_i)^2\right) = 2 \sum_i f_i (a \cdot f_i -g_i)
$$
and thus
$$
a = \frac{\sum f_i g_i}{\sum f_i^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the details. I am actually not sure how to select the target curve $g_i$. Also, could you please suggest if we can express the minimization as a matrix function when multiple curves are present?

Comment: @Natasha: You want to make the curves overlapping. For this, you can select any curve (call that $g$ with values $g_i$), and adjust the $N-1$ others successively (that's the $f_i$). That would be the easiest approach. Moreover, you don't need a "matrix function". Simply solve the the last equation in my answer for $a$ and $b$, and do that for each curve you want to scale separately.

Comment: Could you please see my edit?

Comment: @Natasha: I've also made an edit. My answer (and the others here) assume that you have the curves sampled on the same grid. However, since your last edit it is clear that this is actually not the case. So you'll need some scheme to define the "distance" of two functions. A common approach is to first interpolate onto a common grid, and then use the answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think `a` simplifies to the inverse of what's  shown

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like to ask for a suggestion, if I want to scale $f_i$ (move it a bit up) and also scale $g_i$ (move it a bit down) would it make sense if the objective function is expressed as $(a⋅fi−gi)2 + (b.gi  - fi)^2$. Basically, I want to try and move both the curves towards each other instead of moving one curve towards the other.

Comment: Hi, could you please have a look at my post here https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/using-absolute-error-as-the-cost-function

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution.

1. Find the curve $(x_m, y_m)$ with the largest domain $x$. In your case it is `(x2, y2)`.
2. Assign it to be the main curve and shift all other (non-main) curves toward it.
3. Each non-main curve $(x_k, y_k)$ should be shifted in such a way that its average value equals the average value of the segment of the main curve within the same domain segment as the domain $x_k$ of the non-main curve.

Because the man curve, $(x_m, y_m)$, has the largest domain, make an interpolation for it (e.g. linear), find the values for this curve at all points for other, non-main curves, $(x_k, y_k)$. Then subtract from each non-main curve, $(x_k, y_k)$, its average, and add the average of the main curve values interpolated at $x$-points of the non-main curve, $(x_k, y_k)$.

It is easier to show in code.

My code is in [Julia](https://julialang.org/) but you can do analogously in other languages.

```
using PyPlot, Statistics, Interpolations

scale =  1.5;
x1 = [0,4,6,10,15,20]*scale;
y1 =  [18,17.5,13,12,8,10];
x2 = [0,10.5,28]*scale;
y2= [18.2,10.6,10.3];
x3 = [0,4,6,10,15,20]*scale;
y3 = [18,13,15,12,11,9.6];
x4 = [9,17,28]*scale;
y4 = [5,5.5,7];
x5 = [1,10,20]*scale;
y5 = [3,0.8,2];

plot(x1, y1, "*-", label="y1")
plot(x2, y2, "*-", label="y2")
plot(x3, y3, "*-", label="y3")
plot(x4, y4, "*-", label="y4")
plot(x5, y5, "*-", label="y5")
legend();
```

This gives your original plot

[image]

Then interpolate the curve with the largest domain

```
interp_linear = LinearInterpolation(x2, y2);
```

Then shift all curves toward the main curve so that their averages coincide within the corresponding domain segments

```
plot(x1, y1 .+ mean(interp_linear.(x1)).-mean(y1) , "*-", label="y1")
plot(x2, y2, "*-", label="y2")
plot(x3, y3 .+ mean(interp_linear.(x3)).-mean(y3) , "*-", label="y3")
plot(x4, y4 .+ mean(interp_linear.(x4)).-mean(y4) , "*-", label="y4")
plot(x5, y5 .+ mean(interp_linear.(x5)).-mean(y5) , "*-", label="y5")
legend();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. I like this idea, this preserves the shape of all $x_k$'s i.e the trend of the $x_k$'s before and after shifting doesn't change and I find this great.  I have a few doubts, could you please check my edit 3?

Comment: @Natasha Suppose you have 3 curves. c1 - the main curve - is defined in $0<x<10$. The other (non-main) curves are defined on the intervals: c2 on $0<x<5$; c3 on $5<x<10$. To shift c2, compare its mean not with the mean of the whole main curve but only with that portion of the main curve where you can compare both curves, i.e. on the interval $0<x<5$, where they both are defined. So, take the portion of the main curve on $0<x<5$, and calculate its mean. Then subtract from c2 its mean and add the mean of the portion of the main curve on $0<x<5$. Likewise with c3. Read the code carefully.

Comment: Thanks so much, this clarifies my doubt and also the confusion that I had with the term "segment".  I am not sure how to preserve the order of the curves. i.e in the original data the purple curve is below the red curve; after scaling the curves, the purple curve lies above the red curve. Could you please give some intuition behind using the mean of the main curve and non-main curve to scale the data?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a function as reference $f_r$ the scale-translation transformations for each remaining functions can be handled by minimizing

$$
E(a,b,r) = \sum_{k\ne r}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^n \left(f_k(j)a_k+b_k - f_r(j)\right)^2
$$

or

$$
\min_{a,b,r}E(a,b,r)
$$

Here, for each $r$, the minimization can be accomplished by solving a linear system. As the stationary condition is $\nabla E(a,b,r) = 0$ we have

$$
\cases{
\frac{\partial}{\partial a_k}E(a,b,r) = \sum_j^n f_k(j)^2 a_k + \sum_j^n f_k(j)b_k - \sum_j^n f_k(j)f_r(j) = 0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial b_k}E(a,b,r) = \sum_j^n f_k(j) a_k + \sum_j^n  n b_k - \sum_j^n f_r(j) = 0
}
$$

so at each $r$ we should solve $m-1$, $(2\times 2)$linear systems or instead one of $(2(m-1),2(m-1)).$

$$
\left(\matrix{\sum_j^n f_k(j)^2 & \sum_j^n f_k(j)\\ 
              \sum_j^n f_k(j) & m}\right)
           \left(\matrix{a_k \\ b_k} \right)=\left(\matrix{\sum_j^n f_k(j)f_r(j)\\ \sum_j^n f_r(j)}\right)
$$

In the proposed case study, the best arrangement is shown in the attached figure. Here the base function is the third from top to bottom.

[image]

[image]

NOTE

Code attached: MATHEMATICA.

```
data = {{{157, 60}, {140, 57}, {121, 52}, {103, 47}, {86, 39}, {67, 28}, {50,21}, {32, 15}}, {{159, 70}, {140, 67}, {122, 63}, {105, 58}, {85, 45}, {68, 42}, {50, 34}, {33, 29}}, {{157, 74}, {140, 71}, {121, 70}, {105, 65}, {86, 55}, {69, 52}, {52, 43}, {32, 37}}, {{158, 100}, {141, 100}, {123, 95}, {105, 90}, {88, 78}, {69, 72}, {51, 57}, {33, 46}}, {{160, 143}, {140, 146}, {123, 146}, {105, 145}, {86, 136}, {70, 121}, {51, 97}, {34, 60}}}
gr1 = ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1.3];
gr2 = ListLinePlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1.3];
Show[gr1, gr2]

min = 1000000;
For[r = 1, r <= 5, r++,
 obj = Total[Table[If[k != r, Sum[(data[[k]][[j, 2]] a[k] + b[k] - data[[r]][[j, 2]])^2, {j, 1, 8}], 0], {k, 1, 5}]];
 vars = Flatten[Table[If[k != r, {a[k], b[k]}], {k, 1, 5}]];
 sol = Solve[Grad[obj, vars] == 0, vars][[1]];
 min0 = obj /. sol;
 If[min0 < min, rmin = r; min = min0; coefs = sol]
]

sdata = Table[Table[{data[[k]][[j, 1]], data[[k]][[j, 2]] a[k] + b[k]} /. coefs, {j, 1, 8}], {k, 1, 5}] /. {a[rmin] -> 1, b[rmin] -> 0}

gr1b = ListPlot[sdata, AspectRatio -> 1.3];
gr2b = ListLinePlot[sdata, AspectRatio -> 1.3];
Show[gr1b, gr2b]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you please post your code, if that's ok?

Comment: Included the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm sorry, could you please add comments to these lines of code? Or if possible could you please provide a MATLAB/ python code? And could you please explain `b` ?

Comment: That's a nice picture and shows the result of the shift-and-scale approach from my answer, so thanks for that. However, one should reach for an analytical solution here and not use some iterative minimizer ... not that it would matter in terms of runtimes, but in principle ... we're in a  computational science forum here ;-)

Comment: To solve each minimization step it is necessary to solve a linear system.....

Comment: Right, which is a 2x2 linear system, that one has to solve $N-1$ times. This works analytically, whereas your code uses the Minimize function. Maybe this function is as clever as to solve a linear system, but maybe it's not and then you'll likely end up using some iterative optimizer like Newton. This might be overkill and diffuses the simple analytical structure. But again, that's just a comment on the details, thanks for the solution and the picture.

Comment: @Cesareo Could you please have a look at my recent edit? I would like to ask for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the finite element method books, there is a section called vector-function approximations. There is what you are looking for.

Since there is no target function to approach, you can take a weighted average of all curves to find a target $T$ curve. Then find $A$ values to minimize the total difference.  Minimize this $(f-A-T)^2$.

Minimization is at the beginning of FEM books, in the approximation section. However, it is the subject of optimization methods and can be found even in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain a bit about what A denotes here? From what I read and understand about vector-function approximations, I think by this you are referring to the use of polynomial functions to interpolate the data in each curve and later perform the minimization task.  If possible, could you please share the links to the references/ books?