# Finding weighted average of curves

Tags: optimization, interpolation, geometry, distance-measure, l2-norm

This is related to my previous post [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41552/minimize-distance-between-curves)

I have a dataset with values of multiple curves. An example plot is shown below.
I want to scale the curves (move up/down) so that all curves overlap.

The following is a sample dataset which includes that data points corresponding to 5 curves and coordinate inputs below

```
scale =  1.5;
x1 = [0,4,6,10,15,20]*scale;
y1 =  [18,17.5,13,12,8,10];
x2 = [0,10.5,28]*scale;
y2= [18.2,10.6,10.3];
x3 = [0,4,6,10,15,20]*scale;
y3 = [18,13,15,12,11,9.6];
x4 = [9,17,28]*scale;
y4 = [5,5.5,7];
x5 = [1,10,20]*scale;
y5 = [3,0.8,2];

plot(x1,y1, '*-', x2, y2,  '*-', x3, y3,  '*-', x4, y4,  '*-', x5, y5,  '*-')
```

[image]

To scale the curves, I need to find the scale factor by defining a target curve.
I'm not sure of the ways in which the target curve can be defined. Would it be a good
approach to compute the weighted average? Since the x scale is different for each curve, I am not sure
how to define an average/ target curve.

Suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how you define the "sum of a curve". Do you mean the area under the curve? Or some norm like $\|f\|_2=\int f(x)^2\;dx$?

Comment: Subtract the mean of each curve. Optionally scale each so its RMS = 1.

Comment: @PC1 Thanks for the reply. I mean the average of curves. Please let me know if I am still unclear.

Comment: @Aruralreader Thanks for the reply. Should I compute the mean of each curve and subtract every data point in the curve from the mean? I'm not sure how to scale so that RMS=1. Could you please explain this a bit?

Comment: I would first find a coordinate $x_0$ that all curves intervals include, and then interpolate each curve to that $x_0$. The interpolated value would be the scaling factor for each curve.

Comment: @MaximUmansky, Thank you for the nice idea, I will give this a try. Could you please explain a bit on how the resulting scaling factor for each curve could be used to obtain an average curve, I think the scale factors cannot be used as weights?

Comment: Well, if a given curve $y(x)$ interpolates to $y_0$ at $x_0$ then you scale it as $y(x)/y_0$ (assuming $y_0$ is not zero). Then all scaled curves intersect at $(x_0, 1)$.

Comment: @MaximUmansky But this will still be different curves. I'm not sure if I understand how we could find a target curve from the curves that result after scaling by y0 i.e y(x)/y0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I promised you an answer in the other question, and was just about to edit it in. Now I see you spend another 100 points as a bounty ... seems quite a serious topic to you. I'll post my promised answer, and there's no need to spend the other 100 points on me ...  for what it's worth.

Ok, let's start where we have been in the other thread, and summarize. You'll need:

1. A measure of distance between curves. Otherwise, there is no meaning to set up a target function. One choice mentioned in the other thread was to do an interpolation of the data $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^M$ on a common, and probably finer, set of gridpoints $x_k$, which will produce functions $f_i(x)$, and then simply use the squared difference evaluated on the grid,
   $$
   D(f_i,f_j) = \sum_{k=1}^N | f_i(x_k) - f_j(x_k)|^2
   $$
   As interpolation you can use piecewise linear, polynomial, spline, or any other reasonable choice.
2. A model on how to scale the curves. Let's assume for the moment it is parametrized by a single parameter $\alpha_i$ and produces a function
   $$
   \tilde f_i(x,\alpha_i)
   $$
   In the other thread you seemd to prefer amultiplicative function -- more on that later in this post.
3. A functional what to minimize. In the other thread, we chose a single curve as reference and adjusted the others with respect to thier parameters $\alpha_i$ as to come as close to the reference as possible. In this case, one could simply use the distance $D(\tilde f_i(\alpha_i),f_j)$ as target function. Now, you want all that all curves are scaled at the same time, and so you'll lose the reference curve. With this you could use
   $$
   L(\alpha_i;\lambda) = \sum_{i<j}^M \sum_{k=1}^N | \tilde f_i(x_k,\alpha_i) - \tilde f_j(x_k,\alpha_j)|^2 + \text{some appropriate penalty term on } \alpha_i
   $$
   I've added a penalty term here which imposes that the parameters should be as small as possible. It is necessary because otherwise, depending on the model for the functions, the problem is not uniquely defined (see below) 
   The penalty term could be $\lambda \sum_{i=1}^M| \alpha_i|^2$, for example, with which you would obtain a method called *ridge regression*.
   Now you can pick a $\lambda$ optimize the $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^M$ in order to minimize the functional $L(\alpha_i;\lambda)$.

I'll apply this to some simple models in the following. Everything from here is simple calculus, where I hope I didn't make too many mistakes.

---

**Additive model:**

Let's first apply the concepts above to the model $\tilde f_i(x) = f_i(x) + \alpha_i$. The penalty function is the one from ridge regression (if there would be no such penalty function, for any solution ${\alpha_i}_{i=1}^M$, ${\alpha_i + c}_{i=1}^M$ would also be a solution.

Upon insertion into the functional, one obtains
$$
L(\alpha_i;\lambda) = \sum_{i<j}^M \sum_{k=1}^N | f_i(x_k) + \alpha_i - \tilde f_j(x_k) - \alpha_j|^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^M| \alpha_i|^2
$$
and thus
$$
\partial_{\alpha_i} L = 2\sum_{j=i+1}^M \sum_{k=1}^N  \left(f_i(x_k) + \alpha_i - f_j(x_k) - \alpha_j\right)+ 2\lambda \alpha_i\\
= \left(\sum_{k=1}^N (f_i(x_k)-\sum_{j=i+1}^M f_j(x_k)\right) + (1 + \lambda) \alpha_i -  \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^M \alpha_j \right) = 0
$$
or
$$
\alpha_i= \frac{1}{1+\lambda} \left( \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^M \alpha_j \right) -  \left(f_i(x_k)-\sum_{j=i+1}^M f_j(x_k)\right) \right)
$$

You can solve this iteratively starting from $i=M$ and going down to $i=1$.

---

**Multiplicative model:**

Using the model $\tilde f_i(x) = \alpha_i f_i(x)$. I'll do that some other day, but just want to note, that you need another for of penalty function here, for example $\lambda_i \sum_i \log(\alpha_i)$. Otherwise, e.g. in the ridge regression case before, the global solution would be $\alpha_i=0$, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I'll apply this to a dataset and update my observations here. It has always happened that the questions with bounties are explained in great detail and in a short span :) and I'm happy to spend my points on the solutions posted by experts in the field for the amount of time that is invested:) .Also, if I don't award the bounty I lose points anyway :D

Comment: @Natasha: may I ask -- what is the ultimate goal of this task? In which field do you work, and what kind of data is this? What do you win when the curves overlap?

Comment: Sure, I am using datasets for predictive modeling in biology. The data comes from different sources and is often reported in arbitrary units.  In such cases, I am trying to see if this approach can help in scaling the measurements.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be a good approach to compute the weighted average?

I don't think it would be a good choice (in biology, as marked in comments.) in any case. what is $x$ & what is $y$?

but what for would you like to put-up/down curves to the same level, if they will still remain to be different curves in your analysis?..

I can see from such data opportunities for these 2 sorts of analysis only:

1. you can either find $\frac{dy}{dx}$  approximation of slope for each curve - to make conclusion about **slope** (effect) size (preferably for the same x-values in laboratory or not the same like in reality you have - but in such a case is not understood what you're investigating - if $y$ as effect/result of $x$ exposure?) -- slope, anyway, could show the effect-size (or sensitivity)
2. or analyse $x-\overline{x}$ to conclude about **variation** for each sample

Comment: Welcome to scicomp. A tip: You can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to typeset your mathematical formulas. This will make the question much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected